# Nexus 3.5.1 proxies from snapshot repo nothing but maven metadata files

Tags: clojure, nexus, nexus3, boot-clj, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have upgraded nexus repository from 2.x to 3.x through following path:

2.4.14 -> 3.4.0 -> 3.5.1

All `nexus` services were packed in docker with data directory mapped from host's. For all services I use default either `sonatype/nexus` or `sonatype/nexus3` containers. Nexus web interface is hidden behind `nginx` with simple reverse proxying.

I use the nexus service with `boot-cj` (with no credentials) tools which manages dependencies the same way as maven. Anyway the tool first downloads `nexus-maven.xml` with relevant `sha1` files and tries to download `jars`. It works fine with all `2.x` I had.

I created a proxy repository against remote `sonatype-snapshots` repo. When I start compilation I have `Could not find artifact` error. I found that the meatdata files are cached but all poms and jars.

I have tried to fix it by cleaning cache with the `clean_cache` file trick and more rough `rm -rfv /srv/nexus3/nexus-data/cache/*` with no success. There are no any logs about error. Also I have checked manually that required artefact exists in the remote repository. More obvious `Rebuild index` button gave no solution. I do not thing it is a problem with nginx, but who knows? Also leaving overnight to run the scheduled tasks did not help.

The expected artifact is `org.eclipse.rdf4j:rdf4j:pom:2.3-20170901.145510-11`.

Comment: Probably reason was error with publishing the artefact. More details were given in **RDF4J** [Issue #909](https://github.com/eclipse/rdf4j/issues/909).

Comment: Querying the artifacts differs between nexus2 and nexus3.